# Direct sum of nontrivial vector bundles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

When is it true that the direct sum (or whitney sum) of two nontrivial vector bundles is nontrivial? Also, if you have a direct sum of vector bundles, with $a$ and $b$ global sections respectively, does its direct sum have $a+b$ sections?

Comment: If $\tau$ is the tautological bundle over the circle (aka the 'Mobius bundle'), then $\tau \oplus \tau$ is trivial. For a different example, pick an even-dimensional sphere $S^n$ and an odd-dimensional sphere $S^m$ such that $m$ is not 0, 1, 3, or 7 (i.e. $S^m$ is not parallelizable). Then if $p_i$ are the respective projections onto each factor, $T(S^n \times S^m) \cong p_1^*TS^n \oplus p_2^*TS^m$. One can show $S^n \times S^m$ is trivial, but each of the factors is not.

Comment: @user98602 wow! This incredible adding a trivial bundle to a non-trivial bundle can make it trivial! Adding zero to a non-zero quantity can make it zero! This is all too surprising to me. Bundles are fascinatingly mysterious!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the characteristic classes of your vector bundles, you can compute the characteristic classes of their direct sum, so if any of those don't vanish then the direct sum is nontrivial. Otherwise things are hard. In fact it's known that for any (real or complex) vector bundle $V$ on, say, a compact Hausdorff space, there is another vector bundle $W$ such that $V \oplus W$ is trivial.

Your second question is straightforwardly yes (assuming by "$n$ global sections" you mean "$n$ linearly independent global sections") and the most obvious construction works.